# Как в Electron загрузить большое количество локальных картинок без точного адреса?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

У меня есть приложение на Electron. И у меня есть база данных в JSON, которая выглядит примерно так:

```
[{"name": "HELLO"}, {"name":"WE WILL BE"}, {"name":"HAPPY NOW"}, {"name":"AND FOREVER"}]
```

Также в корне проекта есть папка `assets` и вот её примерная структура:

```
assets/HELLO/

       WE WILL BE/

       HAPPY NOW/

       AND FOREVER/
```

Т.е. у меня есть папки, которые называются так же, как и поля `name` в JSON.

В этих папках лежат файлы (их разное количество и у них разные названия и расширения): `1 file.jpg`, `2 file.jpg`,`3 file.pdf`.

И мне, собственно, нужно сделать так, чтобы из папок, соответствующих полям `name`, загружались только картинки.

Я реализовывал это раньше в React Native и там было достаточно просто – был компонент RNFS, который умел считывать локальные assets в приложении, считывать список файлов и удобно подгружать.

А вот в этом случае я не понимаю, как это сделать. У node есть API для файловой системы, но как я понял, оно читает файлы только во внешней файловой системе, а мне категорически важно сделать так, чтобы все папки и картинки шли вместе с установочником приложения. Т.е. мне нужно вместе с приложением устанавливать все эти папки и файлы куда-то и потом получать к ним доступ.

Подскажите, возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetapppath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было не самым сложным.

1. В конфигурирования electron-builder я добавил `"assets/*/*",` в  `files`. Это позволяло включить в финальный архив все мои изображения.
2. Также я добавил `"asarUnpack" : "assets/*/*"`. У меня возникли некоторые проблемы при получении фото из asar-архива (в который Electron пакует все файлы проекта) и пришлось сделать это.
3. Дальше я просто получал список папок и файлов в них:

   ```
   const electron = window.require('electron').remote
   const fs = electron.require('fs')

   const path = `${electron.app.getAppPath()}.unpacked/photo/${folder_name}`
   ```

   И подключал картинки через file://, предварительно поменяв код запуска окна Electron:

   ```
   const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      show: false,
      width: 1330,
      height: 850, 
      webPreferences: {
         webSecurity: false // это играет ключевую роль, позволяя использовать file://
      }
   })
   ```